# Illumination system gets too hot in android

Tags: android, led

I am developing an android app for measuring heart rate using the camera and the illumination system of the phone in which the user has to place his finger on the camera to detect a pulse. 
 I am testing my app in a NExus 4 device. 
I use this code to access the camera

```
 if(flashSupported==true){
       parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
 } 
 camera.setParameters(parameters);
 camera.startPreview();
```

The heart rate functionality works great, but on my Nexus 4 the LED becomes really hot and the user at some point is unable to keep his finger in the LED. I also tried this on a Nexus S and its also gets really hot. I havent tried it on other devices and I dont really know whether this is a hardware problem or it's a problem on my behalf.

Is there any way I can avoid this problem programmatically?

Comment: The only way you can programatically control the thermal output of an LED on the phone is to turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scott said, the only way to control the thermal output of an LED on the phone is to turn it off. BUT, you could use phone heat sensors to get temperature of your phone and logcat what is over heating your phone. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, its the hardware I guess that makes the LED so hot. I just wanted to know if I could do something on my behalf, to fix this.

Comment: If you have any soldering experience you could try to repair it yourself, but it might be dangerous, even with the right tools. Otherwise you can bring it to a local shop (like chinese one, they are really cheap) and see what they can do for you. I changed my SD-Card Reader for 15€!

Comment: No, I dont want to mess with the hardware, its not that its broken or anything, I guess every nexus 4 is heating up really fast, even without the LED on

Answer (score 1):

it's the output resolution of the camera. most phones that record in 4k res can only record for 5min before it overheats. maybe you can force change the resolution of the camera, or get it to use the front facing camera while still logging biometrics